# What is a word for a very insignificant or small accident?

Tags: single-word-requests, synonyms, common-word

What is the word for very small bad luck or mishap or accident? An example would be like when you get a gravy stain on your shirt while having breakfast. Another example could be, a funny and awkward, you accidentally farted in public. Or maybe your phone crashed when you needed it or  the cap/lid accidently falls off and you ended ruining you dish with awful amount of salt.

> I had a _________ today when I accidentally spilled coffee over me.

Comment: Can you please add an example sentence to the post with a blank for the word you are looking for? Also, what research have you done? Google searches, thesaurus looking, etc?

Comment: @Hank I did search on web, but didn't find anything without adjective.

Comment: Add that information to the post. Add that you google searched but could only find adjectives and you need a noun with an adjective. Also, what is wrong with "mishap" or "accident"?

Comment: I'd say **mishap**, which you mention in your question, fits pretty well.

Comment: @Drew boo-boo, informal but it's a good one, actually it's informality express it's insignificance.

Comment: Goof is similar.

Comment: I often use *hiccup*.

Comment: I agree, **mishap**.  I was going to write an answer, but the definitions I found make it sound like a bigger deal than it really is.  Another possibility would be **glitch**.

Answer (score 1):

Perhaps, ***hitch*** fits here.

> I had a ***hitch*** today when I accidentally spilled coffee over myself.

Macmillan:

> **[hitch](http://www.macmillandictionary.com/dictionary/american/hitch_2)** *NOUN* [COUNTABLE]
>   **a problem that is not very serious**
>   The
>   airplane was delayed because of a last-minute hitch.